# Tooltip css class lost after web service call via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, webmethod

I have a jquery web service that affects css class of tooltip on the same page.

The problem is this; when the page initially loads, tooltip css works fine, but after web service call vith a button on page, tooltip class lost and it is shown as standard view. What will cause this?

```js
c# Code Block

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SampleWeb {
  public partial class Sample: System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (!IsPostBack) {
        GetDataForPageLoad();
      }
    }

    public void GetDataForPageLoad() {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      lblData.Text = string.Format("<a title=\"click to view topic {0}.\" class=\"masterTooltip\"><img width=\"50px\" src='images/Chrysanthemum.jpg' alt=\"{0}\"  /></a><br/>", "XXX");
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetData() {
      return string.Format("<a title=\"click to view topic {0}.\" class=\"masterTooltip\"><img width=\"50px\" src='images/Chrysanthemum.jpg' alt=\"{0}\"  /></a><br/>", "XXX");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleWeb.Sample" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">

    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .tooltip {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #b83e3e;
        background-color: #d84949;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #fff;
      }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
      function GetData() {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:6878/Sample.aspx/GetData',
          type: 'POST',
          data: '',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: function(data) {

            var obj = document.getElementById("lblData");
            obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + data.d;
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get" onclick="GetData();" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>



      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          // Tooltip only Text
          $('.masterTooltip').hover(function() {
            // Hover over code
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
            $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
              .text(title)
              .appendTo('body')
              .fadeIn('slow');
          }, function() {
            // Hover out code
            $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
            $('.tooltip').remove();
          }).mousemove(function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
            var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
            $('.tooltip')
              .css({
                top: mousey,
                left: mousex
              })
          });
        });
      </script>



    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I suspect this line is your problem:

```
obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + data.d;
```

You hook up your tooltips with this line:

```
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function() {
```

which hooks up a `hover` handler on all `.masterTooltip` elements on the page ... at that moment (with "that moment" being when the page loads and triggers the DOM ready event).

But when you mess with the `innerHTML` of an element you are effectively removing the old elements and replacing them with new ones, and since you haven't hooked up a `hover` handler to those new ones, they don't work.

If I'm correct I see two possible solutions:

1) Put all that `$('.masterTooltip').hover(function() {` code inside a function.  Call that function `onReady`, as you currently are, but then call it again after the `innerHTML` change to hook up the handler to the new elements

2) Don't remove the old elements at all; instead of using innerHTML to replace the old `lblData` contents:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("lblData");
obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + data.d;
```

try using jQuery to just add a new element:

```
$('#lblData').append('<span>' + data.id + '</span>');
// I'm not even sure the span is needed, but I added it to be safe
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. We will try your solutions immediately.

Comment: Hello again,  the first solution made the first image work tooltip correctly but second image is still has default tooltip. But the second solution worked fine.  We made function RegisterHover() and called it in jquery request. Then it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

[sample run before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U83hC.jpg)

I wrote new code block for accepted solution as shown above.

```js
 <script>

        function GetData() {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:27738/WebForm3.aspx/GetData',
                type: 'POST',
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {

                    var obj = document.getElementById("lblData");
                    obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + data.d;


                  
                    //Call RegisterHover
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        registerHover();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

```html
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get" onclick="GetData();" /><br /><br />

        <asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <!--call at ready-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                registerHover();
            });

            //New function
            function registerHover() {
                // Tooltip only Text
                $('.masterTooltip').hover(function () {
                    // Hover over code

                    // alert("test");

                    var title = $(this).attr('title');
                    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                    .text(title)
                    .appendTo('body')
                    .fadeIn('slow');
                }, function () {
                    // Hover out code
                    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                    $('.tooltip').remove();
                }).mousemove(function (e) {
                    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
                    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
                    $('.tooltip')
                    .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
                });
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```